# OPC UA Client MonitoredDataItem - What is MonitoredDataItem MonitoringMode.Reporting vs MonitoringMode.Sampling?

Tags: opc-ua

The sampling rate is bound by Subscription's PublishingInterval.
What is the difference between the two MonitoringModes? I can't find any information anywhere that describes them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't find any information anywhere that describes them.

OPC UA Spec Part 4 describes them in detail, but the TL;DR version is: `Reporting` means the client is actually sent data change notifications for these items, `Sampling` means the item is only sampled and value changes put into the queue each monitored item has, but changes are not actually reported to the client.

Comment: Thanks very much - I'll go look at that part of the specification.

Comment: I suppose you're referring to this section? https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/Core/docs/Part4/5.12.1/#5.12.1.3

Comment: New to OPC UA. Out of curiosity, what is the use if samples are added but no notifications enabled? i.e when we use 'Sampling' mode?

Comment: @AMJ it’s really only useful if the client will re-enable ‘Reporting’ mode at some point in the future and doesn’t want to miss the possible data changes that occurred since then. The other possibility is they set it to ‘Disabled’ temporarily for some reason and will re-enable ‘Reporting’ later.